# Skin control, different syntax with CSS

Tags: c#, themes, skin

I have a question about the layout control by skin (Theme)

I want the img to be horizontal centered, however, the syntax of *.skin is a little different with CSS,

I write like this

```
<asp:image Skinid="homepage"    
  runat="server"    
  imageUrl="/"./image/home_pic.png     
  style="margin:0 auto"    
  bordwe="0"    
  ImageAlign="Right"/>
```

**ImageAlign="Right" works!** But **ImageAlign="center"** does not work

I have also tried **Align and Float**, but both of them don't work

Is anybody can sharing some solutions,really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a list of valid values for the ImageAlign property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imagealign.aspx).

Try using a normal img tag instead, with either style="margin:0 auto; display: block" or within a centered paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, before i use skin, i use normal img tag with CSS. However, here i was required to use skin, so i am a little confused! Thank you for your answer